# Analyticity of a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, analyticity

I was reading a physics paper and the author made a statement that I didn't follow.

Suppose $p(t)$ is given by the Fourier transform of $\omega(E)$

\begin{equation}
p(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-iEt}\omega(E)dE,
\end{equation}

where $\omega(E)$ is a function that is zero for $E \leq 0$. Now lets make the variable $t$ complex: $t = t_1 + it_2$ and define $p_1(t) \equiv p(-t)$. So:

\begin{equation}
p_1(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{iEt_1}e^{-Et_2}\omega(E)dE.
\end{equation}

Now he claims that $p_1(t)$ is an analytical function in the upper plane ($t_2 > 0$) because $\omega(E)$ is semi-finite (*i.e.* $\omega(E) = 0 $ for $E \leq 0$). Why is that? Isn't $p_1(t)$ analytical in the whole plane?

In my understanding for a complex function $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ to be analytic it must obey the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

Which the function $p_1(t)$ definitively obeys for all $t_1$ and $t_2$. Why is $E$ even important in this context?

For anyone interested, the paper is: 
*Khalfin, L. A.*, Sov. Phys. JETP **6**, 1053 (1958).
My question is in the paragraph right after equation (2.5).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\omega(E)=0$ for $E<0$ means that the lower integration limit $E\to-\infty$ can be replaced with $E\to0$. So, in what remains of the integral, $E$ is positive. That means $-Et_2$, in the exponential, has the opposite sign of $t_2$; if $t_2$ is negative, then you're integrating $e^{+E}dE$ to infinity, which diverges (in general; it may converge for specific $\omega$).

Comment: Thanks man, that makes sense.